# Multiple Array with foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I would like to add more then 1 Attachment to the an email in PHP. My current code is below. It's a e-mail form that sends multiple attachments to an email.

Any ideas on how to get it working? Do I need a foreach loop in the Array $Anhang? Thanks!

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);

function mail_att($to,$subject,$message,$anhang) 
   { 
   $absender = "xxx"; 
   $absender_mail = "xxx@xxx.com"; 
   $reply = "info@xxx.xxx"; 

   $mime_boundary = "-----=" . md5(uniqid(mt_rand(), 1)); 

   $header  ="From:".$absender."<".$absender_mail.">\n"; 
   $header .= "Reply-To: ".$reply."\n"; 

   $header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
   $header.= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n"; 
   $header.= " boundary=\"".$mime_boundary."\"\r\n"; 

   $content = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n\r\n"; 
   $content.= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n"; 
   $content.= "Content-Type: text/html charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\r\n"; 
   $content.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\r\n\r\n"; 
   $content.= $message."\r\n"; 

   //$anhang ist ein Mehrdimensionals Array 
   //$anhang enthält mehrere Dateien 
   if(is_array($anhang) AND is_array(current($anhang))) 
      { 
      foreach($anhang AS $dat) 
         { 
         $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($dat['data'])); 
         $content.= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n"; 
         $content.= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n"; 
         $content.= "\tfilename=\"".$dat['name']."\";\r\n"; 
         $content.= "Content-Length: .".$dat['size'].";\r\n"; 
         $content.= "Content-Type: ".$dat['type']."; name=\"".$dat['name']."\"\r\n"; 
         $content.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
         $content.= $data."\r\n"; 
         } 
      $content .= "--".$mime_boundary."--";  
      } 
   else //Nur 1 Datei als Anhang 
      { 
      $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($anhang['data'])); 
      $content.= "--".$mime_boundary."\r\n"; 
      $content.= "Content-Disposition: attachment;\r\n"; 
      $content.= "\tfilename=\"".$anhang['name']."\";\r\n"; 
      $content.= "Content-Length: .".$dat['size'].";\r\n"; 
      $content.= "Content-Type: ".$anhang['type']."; name=\"".$anhang['name']."\"\r\n"; 
      $content.= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n"; 
      $content.= $data."\r\n"; 
      }  




   if(@mail($to, $subject, $content, $header)) return true; 
   else return false; 
   } 

echo "Dein Name Bitch ist ".  $_POST["name"] . "<br>" . $_FILES["Bild1"]["name"];

$anhang = array(); 
$anhang["name"] = $_FILES['Bild1']['name']; 
$anhang["size"] = $_FILES['Bild1']['size']; 
$anhang["type"] = $_FILES['Bild1']['type']; 
$anhang["data"] = implode("",file($_FILES['Bild1']['tmp_name'])); 

mail_att("info@xxx","Email mit Anhang","Im Anhang ist eine Datei",$anhang); 

?>
```

Comment: I have  $_FILES['Bild2'], $_FILES['Bild3'], $_FILES['Bild4'] and $_FILES['Bild5'] and need to store it in the $anhang array...i guess thats the problem. any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over all the uploaded files:

```
$anhang = array();
foreach ($_FILES as $curfile) {
    if (!empty($curfile['name'])) {
        $curfile['data'] = file_get_contents($curfile['tmp_name']);
        $anhang[] = $curfile;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried it like that. i recieve the email with attachments but i cant open the attachments....

Comment: do i have to add   $anhang["name"] = file_get_contents($_FILES['name']); 
  $anhang["size"] = file_get_contents($_FILES['size']); 
  $anhang["type"] = file_get_contents($_FILES['type']);

Comment: `$anhang[] = $curfile;` initializes the array with a copy of `$curfile`, which already has the `name`, `size`, and `type` elements.

Comment: But there were other problems, I just fixed them.